# MVC Login Page with Custom Layout and ViewStart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem I cannot wrap my head around, it is driving me crazy. I used the default template for MVC projects in VS2013 and everything works fine. I can login with users I've created using the Forms Authentication, etc. The problem I have is that when I drop a _ViewStart into the Account views folder, and use a custom layout for the login pages ... I keep getting redirected to the login page everytime I try to login. My Login Post method is also not being called, only the Default Login ActionResult fires. If I take the ViewStart file out and use the default layout, I have no problems.

Here is my _LoginLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Corporate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/style.css">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="holder login">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 left">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="~/images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 border">
                <img src="~/images/corporate.png" alt="corporate" />
                <br />

                <form>
                    @RenderBody()
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Application. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </footer>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the ViewStart...

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

The login page is basically the same boiler plate page provided when you start the project. Everything works until I start trying to use a custom layout and viewstart.

Comment: Not related, but you appear to be rendering the jquery script twice, one in the head (`@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")`) and again at the bottom of the page (`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`). Why do you need a `_ViewStart` in the Account views folder? Your login page just needs to specify the layout to use

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for pointing that out. Having a _ViewStart within the Views folder allows you to specify a Layout to use for all pages within that folder, rather than going into each View and setting the Layout Manually and then having to maintain it if things change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm dumb.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account",....
```

Creates Form tags. My layout had Form tags wrapping the RenderBody(). I was essentially nesting form tags which is a nono. Mystery solved.

It's the little things that get you.